# Magento 2.3 after installation problem with intl

Tags: configuration, installation, http-error-500

I have a problem with Magento 2.3.5 After installation when i go to magento i see error 500. In my error log is

```
[Mon Sep 28 10:02:41.724732 2020] [php7:error] [pid 29850] [client 89.64.6.204:49120] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

I have installed INTL for php

```
/etc/php.d/20-intl.ini,
intl
intl.default_locale => no value => no value
intl.error_level => 0 => 0
intl.use_exceptions => 0 => 0
```

My PHP version:

```
PHP 7.3.22 (cli) (built: Sep  1 2020 09:44:58) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.22, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.22, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Do you have any idea why it does not work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in magento 2.1.8](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193891/getting-fatal-error-class-intldateformatter-not-found-in-magento-2-1-8)

Comment: @Litsher-Nathan I try solution from this answer and I still have error 500 and this same log